# Generics in protocols

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have a `UnitDimension` class given by:

```
class UnitDimension: {
    var symbol: String
    init(symbol: String) {
        self.symbol = symbol
    }
}
```

and a `UnitVolume` subclass of this class:

```
class UnitVolume: UnitDimension {
    static let liter = UnitVolume(symbol: "L")
}
```

I want to have a protocol `UnitDimensionHandler` that allows me to perform some simple functions. Firstly it must have an `allUnits` variable:

```
protocol UnitDimensionHandler: class {
    static var allUnits: [UnitDimension] { get }
}
```

**Is it possible to have `allUnits` a generic type of array that must be a subclass of `UnitDimension`?** I could then implement it in `UnitVolume` as follows:

```
extension UnitVolume: UnitDimensionHandler {
    static var allUnits: [UnitVolume] {
        return [liter]
    }
}
```

I then want to include a function that also allows me to use a generic subclass type that initiates a `UnitDimension` instance:

```
extension UnitDimensionHandler {
    static func unit(for symbol: String) -> UnitDimension? {
        return allUnits.first() { $0.symbol == symbol }
    }
}
```

such that `UnitVolume.unit(for: "L")` returns an optional `UnitVolume` rather than an optional `UnitDimension`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using `associatedtype`:

```
protocol UnitDimensionHandler: class {
    // here we define `generic` type variable `Dimension`, and specify it do be descendant of `UnitDimension`
    associatedtype Dimension: UnitDimension

    // and use it here, instead of `UnitDimension`
    static var allUnits: [Dimension] { get }
}
```

And

```
extension UnitDimensionHandler {
    // same `UnitDimension` -> `Dimension` replacement
    static func unit(for symbol: String) -> Dimension? {
        return allUnits.first() { $0.symbol == symbol }
    }
}
```